# Modify property in a list with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Say I want to modify a `Movie` in a view.
 We can do it by the code.

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Movie</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

However it is for one movie. But I have many movies say 5. The movie model is a list. How can I loop through it?

Comment: have a look, might be helpful : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191769/AJAX-CRUD-in-Grid-using-JQuery-DataTables-in-ASP-N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller/view model":

```
public class MovieViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexValid3(IList<MovieViewModel> movieViewModel)
    {
        //set breakpoint here and update db here
        return View(movieViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult IndexValid3()
    {
        IList<MovieViewModel> list = new List<MovieViewModel>();
        var movieViewModel = new MovieViewModel { ID = 1, Title = "title1"};
        var movieViewModel2 = new MovieViewModel { ID = 1, Title = "title2"};
        list.Add(movieViewModel);
        list.Add(movieViewModel2);
        return View(list);
    }
```

View:

```
@model IList<Testy20161006.Controllers.MovieViewModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexValid3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <table>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].ID)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Title)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the `foreach` inside `@using (Html.BeginForm())` or outside it?

Comment: @Bigeyes inside.

Comment: But I want to edit it, `li` element doesn't work for it. Only `@html.EditorFor`. If you could, please paste all code. Because I get the error `Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@".`